# Как правильно реализовать таблицу, отражающую дерево папок?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Разрабатываю проект "файловое хранилище". Короче делаю свой простой файлообменник. Где пользователи регистрируются, могут загружить файлы, распределять их по папкам, задавать различные уровни доступа для файлов. 
Первая проблема о которой задумался, как вообще правильно реализовать хранения структуры каталогов. Я набросал примерную схему бд http://dbdesigner.net/designer/schema/23655 .Папка хранятся в таблице UserDirectories. Основные поля таблицы: id, parent, name, user. 
parent - это id папки, которая является контейнером для данной папки. Т.е parent - это внешний ключ, который ссылается на свою же таблицу, на поле id.
name - называние папки , user - пользователь, чья папка. Посмотрите, на диаграмме все проще. Я пробовал экспортировать диаграмму в sql - ms sql не может выполнить запрос на создание внешнего ключа, который ссылается на свою же таблицу, ибо это может привести к зацикливанию.

Comment: P.S. когда пройдете по ссылке  -может показаться, что диаграмму пустая - это не так, нужно подвигать горизонтальные и вертикальные ползунки

Comment: Как я понимаю, вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли создать "внешний" ключ, который ссылается на эту же таблицу?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли создать "внешний" ключ, который ссылается на эту же таблицу? В общем-то да, поступают ли так нормальные люди? И как правильней отразить дерево папок в бд ? правильный ли мой подход или может может быть он не желателен?

Comment: _"не может выполнить запрос на создание внешнего ключа, который ссылается на свою же таблицу, ибо это может привести к зацикливанию"_ попробуйте вручную создать, указав `on update no action` и `on delete no action`.

Comment: @Pavel Да, нормальные люди именно так и поступают. Иерархические по своей природе данные следует хранить именно деревом со ссылкой таблицы саму на себя. Это работает.

Comment: @Mike, в MS SQL есть иерархический тип данных. Который позволяет избежать рекурсии при поиске по дереву при составлении запросов.

Comment: У меня вопрос по схеме. Связь между _UserFiles_ и _UserDirectories_, я её не вижу. Как вы будете раскладывать файлы по директориям? Вообще, если следовать модели файловой системы, то возможно файлы и директории должны быть в одной таблице.

Comment: @i-one, хороший вопрос. Большое спасибо, что рассмотрели диаграмму. Случайно удалил связь. В UserFiles было поле DirectoriesID. Благодаря этому можно было определить, какой папке принадлежит файл. Думаете все же нужно в одну таблицу?

Comment: Если планируется что-то близкое к полноценной файловой системе, то возможно так и стоит всё организовать, если же по факту директория будет что-то типа категории, т.е. вложенность не будет использоваться часто (или вообще не будет), то может быть и не стоит. Также обратите внимание, что начиная с SqlServer 2012 появился специальный тип таблиц [`FileTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff929144.aspx), возможно вы захотите использовать эту функциональность. Там как раз иерархия директорий с файлами, на такую таблицу можно ссылаться из других таблиц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш редактор диаграмм, судя по всему, NO ACTION задавать не умеет, поэтому удалите эту связь, и создайте руками после импорта.

Если создаете через дизайнер - убедитесь что INSERT / DELETE Rule выставлен в NO Action:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если создаете кодом - то явно укажите NO ACTION:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table_1_Table_11 
FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) 
REFERENCES dbo.Table_1 (Id) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
ON DELETE  NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

> ms sql не может выполнить запрос на создание внешнего ключа, который ссылается на свою же таблицу

В таблице ссылку саму на себя можно сделать так:

```
CREATE TABLE Files (
   Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   ParentId INT REFERENCES Files(Id)
)
```

Comment: Так тоже создастся внешний ключ на себя. Это просто сокращённый синтаксис, который позволяет не указывать имя ключа явно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот известный обзор [(презентация)](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data?ref=http://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/) к построению деревьев, правда на My SQL.